# getting the signal strength of AP in a particular channel in c

Tags: c

I tried to parse the nested attribute NL80211_CMD_GET_INFO but it shows operation not supported.So how do i use NL80211_CMD_GET_SURVEY to get survey information and then switch channel

Comment: Simply activate the TX375_CMD_INTERPHASE!

Comment: @ooga But never reverse the polarity

Comment: could you tell a little more in detail